Effect of python interpreter and environment on wheel creation
I wrote a python package that I want to publish. I created a setup.py file for it and managed to create a wheel file by running python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel.
My question is whether the python interpreter that I run the command with affects the created wheel and its compatibilities somehow, for example:

Does it matter which packages are installed on the interpreter? For example if the interpreter has different packages installed than specified in the install_requires parameters in the setup.py file.
Can the operating system affect the wheel compatibility? For example if I run the command on a windows machine will I be able to install it seamlessly on a linux machine?

My current understanding is that both of these things shouldn't matter but I'm afraid something unexpected might break.
thanks.

The packages installed on the interpreter will not matter since there is a fresh install every time you run setup.py. The packages that are in the install_requires section of your setup.py will determine the packages that are used for your wheel.
Regarding your second question, yes, the wheel can be OS specific if you don't take precautions. Usually, the wheel only is OS-locked if it includes a complied extension, so be mindful of that. You can also include the the below code in setup.py to make the wheel OS agnostic:
setup(
    options={
        'bdist_wheel': {
            'universal': True,
        },
    },

)

Wyatt Reed's answer is correct, but I'll add that if you do want to compile an extension module for multiple operating systems (and/or multiple versions of python), you should use pypa/cibuildwheel.  This is basically a script that uses a bunch of virtual machines to build your wheel for a variety of common systems.
